# Why is a private member function of a subclass callable from the parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-modifiers

I expect he below code to give an error but [Compiles ok](http://ideone.com/oxSX9q)

```
class B;

template<typename T>
class A
{
    private: 
    A()
    {
       T b;
       b.print();
    }

    void print()
    {

    }
 };

 class B: public A<B>
 {

 };
```

How is `A` capable of accessing the private members, the constructor `A()` and `print()` of `B`?

Comment: Did you see your _'Compiles ok'_ link ?

Comment: Its because you have not instantiate the template class. You can not generate a compiler error in A until you you force it to generate code for A with a specific version of `T`.

Comment: You MUST SEE [Compiles ok](http://ideone.com/6Gc4wR) link. It does NOT compile AT ALL.

Comment: Will look into the standard. The link gives an error after editing it to create an instance of B, without which the compilation is successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to new a class B instance, it will compile error.

> B b;